# HTTP Status- /ehour

Tags: http, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm attempting to run an application "ehour" on Tomcat. When I enter in my browser http://localhost:8080/ehour I get the error HTTP Status 404-/ehour. I've downloaded the mysql connector file and extracted and copied the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar file into tomcat's bin directory and restarted tomcat but still get the same error. This is the error that shows in the tomcat log

```
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:47)
... 69 more".
```

Comment: You should put mysql driver jar into tomcat's `lib` dir instead of `bin`.